# Keyboard stop working

Tags: keyboard

I have a Corsair Gaming Strafe MX keyboard is not detected by Ubuntu 16.04. After grub when I have to login the keyboard and mouse doesn't work. After login by using another keyboard and a few seconds my mouse starts working again. But the keyboard does not. I know it gets power because the leds on it lights up.

I got this problem after I install xpad to get my xbox one controllers to work. So I tried to remove xpad but still have problem with my keyboard.

My mouse have worked fine before but I sometimes had problem with that I had to unplug and plugin the keyboard again.

Edit:

I get following message in dmesg when pluging it out and in again.

```
[ 2992.745185] usb 3-9: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[ 2997.953404] usb 3-9: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/all
[ 2997.953407] usb 3-9: can't read configurations, error -110
[ 2998.073332] usb 3-9: new full-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[ 3003.329543] usb 3-9: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/all
[ 3003.329546] usb 3-9: can't read configurations, error -110
[ 3003.449481] usb 3-9: new full-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[ 3003.470973] usb 3-9: New USB device found, idVendor=1b1c, idProduct=1b15
[ 3003.470975] usb 3-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 3003.470975] usb 3-9: Product: Corsair STRAFE Gaming Keyboard
[ 3003.470976] usb 3-9: Manufacturer: Corsair
[ 3003.470977] usb 3-9: SerialNumber: 1400C031AEB8046955A3033DF5001947
[ 3003.472291] input: Corsair Corsair STRAFE Gaming Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-9/3-9:1.0/0003:1B1C:1B15.0004/input/input20
[ 3003.529745] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B15.0004: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Corsair Corsair STRAFE Gaming Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-9/input0
[ 3013.569843] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B15.0005: usb_submit_urb(ctrl) failed: -1
[ 3013.569855] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B15.0005: timeout initializing reports
[ 3013.570087] input: Corsair Corsair STRAFE Gaming Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-9/3-9:1.1/0003:1B1C:1B15.0005/input/input21
[ 3013.630047] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B15.0005: input,hiddev0,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Corsair Corsair STRAFE Gaming Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-9/input1
[ 3013.630093] usbhid 3-9:1.2: couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint
[ 3019.014851] usb 3-9: USB disconnect, device number 11
[ 3020.349971] usb 3-9: new full-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
```

Comment: If anyone come here hoping to find a solution, I'm sad to say that I have none. I solved my problem by selling the keyboard and buying a new one and this time with some research.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known problem with Corsair keyboards, and as yet there are workarounds but no real solution.
You might want to look at [ckb-next](https://github.com/ckb-next/ckb-next) for some workarounds and a driver that might help:

scroll to the "Troubleshooting" section and look for Linux.

I have had reasonable success by adding the following to `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbhid.quirks=0x1B1C:0x1B13:0x20000408,0x1B1C:0x1B12:0x20000408,0x1B1C:0x1B20:0x20000408"
```

After you add this, run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

to record the changes, then reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue using Corsair K70 LUX... I regain the keyboard by plugging it out and back in after reboot. However it stays 'connected' during sleep sessions.

```
Jan 25 08:47:28 dev-lin kernel: [    1.956077] usb 3-8: new full-speed USB 
device number 5 using xhci_hcd
Jan 25 08:47:33 dev-lin kernel: [    7.392186] usb 3-8: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/all
Jan 25 08:47:33 dev-lin kernel: [    7.392189] usb 3-8: can't read configurations, error -110
Jan 25 08:47:33 dev-lin kernel: [    7.512102] usb 3-8: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Jan 25 08:47:38 dev-lin kernel: [   12.768122] usb 3-8: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/all
Jan 25 08:47:38 dev-lin kernel: [   12.768124] usb 3-8: can't read configurations, error -110
Jan 25 08:47:38 dev-lin kernel: [   12.888085] usb 3-8: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
Jan 25 08:47:49 dev-lin kernel: [   23.264106] usb 3-8: string descriptor 0 read error: -110
Jan 25 08:47:49 dev-lin kernel: [   23.264109] usb 3-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1b1c, idProduct=1b36
Jan 25 08:47:49 dev-lin kernel: [   23.264110] usb 3-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jan 25 08:47:54 dev-lin kernel: [   28.384336] usb 3-8: can't set config #1, error -110
Jan 25 08:47:54 dev-lin kernel: [   28.508072] usb 3-11: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
Jan 25 08:47:54 dev-lin kernel: [   28.666667] usb 3-11: New USB device found, idVendor=1b1c, idProduct=1c0b
Jan 25 08:47:54 dev-lin kernel: [   28.666668] usb 3-11: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jan 25 08:47:54 dev-lin kernel: [   28.666669] usb 3-11: Product:                       
Jan 25 08:47:54 dev-lin kernel: [   28.666669] usb 3-11: Manufacturer:                          
Jan 25 08:47:54 dev-lin kernel: [   28.670936] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1C0B.0007: hiddev4,hidraw6: USB HID v1.11 Device [                                                ] on usb-0000:00:14.0-11/input0
Jan 25 08:48:41 dev-lin kernel: [   75.237734] usb 3-8: USB disconnect, device number 7
Jan 25 08:48:43 dev-lin kernel: [   76.866556] usb 3-8: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
Jan 25 08:48:43 dev-lin kernel: [   77.008277] usb 3-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1b1c, idProduct=1b36
Jan 25 08:48:43 dev-lin kernel: [   77.008281] usb 3-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jan 25 08:48:43 dev-lin kernel: [   77.008283] usb 3-8: Product: Corsair Gaming K70 LUX Keyboard 
Jan 25 08:48:43 dev-lin kernel: [   77.008285] usb 3-8: Manufacturer: Corsair
Jan 25 08:48:43 dev-lin kernel: [   77.008287] usb 3-8: SerialNumber: 03029040AEB89C4755B969BDF5001944
Jan 25 08:48:43 dev-lin kernel: [   77.010046] input: Corsair Corsair Gaming K70 LUX Keyboard  as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-8/3-8:1.0/0003:1B1C:1B36.0008/input/input18
Jan 25 08:48:43 dev-lin kernel: [   77.067149] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B36.0008: input,hidraw7: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Corsair Corsair Gaming K70 LUX Keyboard ] on usb-0000:00:14.0-8/input0
Jan 25 08:48:43 dev-lin kernel: [   77.069367] input: Corsair Corsair Gaming K70 LUX Keyboard  as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-8/3-8:1.1/0003:1B1C:1B36.0009/input/input19
Jan 25 08:48:43 dev-lin kernel: [   77.127251] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B36.0009: input,hiddev5,hidraw8: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Corsair Corsair Gaming K70 LUX Keyboard ] on usb-0000:00:14.0-8/input1
Jan 25 08:48:43 dev-lin kernel: [   77.127367] usbhid 3-8:1.2: couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint
```